Clang float infinity divided by infinity produces different result with optimization flag
I just discovered that when dividing float infinity by itself, results in a different NaN on clang when compiling with any optimization option.
std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()/std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()
results in the following bit sets:

01111111110000000000000000000000 when compiling with -O1, and
11111111110000000000000000000000 when compiling without it.

The difference is only in the sign bit.
I assume the decision of how to represent NaNs is compiler-dependent, but I am surprised that we would see different representations within the same compiler. GCC and MSVC appear to be consistent (11111111110000000000000000000000) regardless of optimization.
My questions are:

Should we expect a consistent result across compilers regardless of optimization?
Should we expect a consistent result within a single compiler regardless of optimization?


Not sure if -O1 enables -ffast-math on clang but to check add -fno-fast-math to make sure it is off and then check.

https://godbolt.org/z/65qqeGz1a

Shrug. Getting a NaN indicates that something went wrong in the calculation. So the next step is to discard the result, or, perhaps, redo the calculation differently. It's only rarely useful to try to parse the NaN. And note that IEEE-754 doesn't provide for different bit patterns for NaNs; that's an Intel thing, not necessarily supported on other hardware.

As far as I remember, IEEE-754 only specifies that the result of operation on NAN is NAN, it doesn't say anything about a particular bit pattern, and I don't see how that can be useful.

@Neal Kruis What happens when you add -ffp-model=precise or -ffp-model=strict after specifying -O<level>? While I also like the INFINITY/INFINITY idiom to create a NaN, you might want to try using the predefined macro NAN from cmath.

-fno-trapping-math lets gcc compute the division at compile-time and give +NaN.

Thanks, @njuffa and @Marc Glisse! -ffp-model=precise and -fno-trapping-math both give consistent results. However, It's still clear though that C++ doesn't guarantee anything about the sign bit in a NaN and it cannot be relied on for distinguishing different NaN types.



Should we expect a consistent result across compilers regardless of optimization?

Should we expect a consistent result within a single compiler regardless of optimization?



The behaviors you report for Clang and the other compilers conform both to C++ and to IEEE-754, even if the sign bit varies from circumstance to circumstance, per below.
A scan of the C++ standard (2020 draft N4849) does not show anything that specifies what the sign of a NaN result should be.
C++ does not require implementations to conform to IEEE-754. Nonetheless, supposing an implementation does, then IEEE-754 2019 (draft D2.47, March 2019) 6.3 “The sign bit” says:

… For all other operations, this standard does not specify the sign
bit of a NaN result, even when there is only one input NaN, or when the NaN is produced from an invalid
operation…

“all other operations” includes division, as the operations discussed prior to this are copy, negate, abs, copySign, totalOrder, and isSignMinus.
